# How to print error message and stack trace into page in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, error-handling, liferay-6.2

I want to print error message and stack trace for every Exception raised in portlet into page so user can see it. I am using Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1 (Newton / Build 6210 / November 1, 2013) with Tomcat.
I tried set up:

```
error.message.show=true
error.stack.trace.show=true
```

in properties files `portal-ext.properties` and `portal.properties` of theme and portlet, but it doesn't work.
I think, maybe it could be done by hook rewriting `portlet_error.jsp`, but I don't know if Liferay has some object, where raised Exception is set. I don't want to rewrite every class, where Exception may be raised. Maybe that exists some another solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?